# Using a decorator to prevent constructor override

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constructor, decorator

```
def no_override(const):
    def wrapper(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        const()
    return wrapper

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hey there')
        print('my name is')
        print('hello')
        self.a = 10

class World(Hello):
    @no_override
    def __init__(self):
        print('and this is')
        print('the other constructor')
        self.b = 20
```

Instead of writing

```
super().__init__(self)
```

inside the constructor of a derived class, all the time, I want to make a @no_override decorator that would do that for me.
But, I am not able to make it access the super class.

```
>>> w = World()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "deco_overriding_prevent.py", line 5, in wrapper
    super().__init__(self)
RuntimeError: super(): __class__ cell not found
>>>
```

Comment: If and when your `__init__`s accept arguments, and different arguments at that, it'll be really messy to invoke the super method through a generic decorator… Is this really a problem that needs solving? What's the advantage of trading the line `super().__init__()` for `@no_override`?

Comment: This is just a very basic work case.
But imagine if we want to selectively add functionality to the entire class without overriding the member methods. Then, use of decorators will improve readability of code.

P.S. I, myself am a beginner and thought that this is something I could learn.